# Month, Year and Countif

Tags: excel, countif

I am trying to develop  a query which should pick out and count the data from a data pool corresponding to the year/month in the given (A106) cell.

While such (array) construct works:

```
COUNTIF(IF(MONTH(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=MONTH(A106);Data.$B$1463:$B$1827);">0");
```

such one - does not:

```
COUNTIF(IF( MONTH(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=MONTH(A106) and  YEAR(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=YEAR(A106));Data.$B$1463:$B$1827);">0")
```

It there anything to be done about it or it is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you might want to use a sumproduct for this (though there are certainly other ways to achieve the same result). This might do the trick:

```
SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=MONTH($A$106))*(YEAR(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=YEAR($A$106)))
```

Comment: "SUMPRODUCT: Multiplies corresponding elements in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products."

I do not catch - what is the reason to use sumproduct(), if I need to filter out and count _the number_ of specific occurances being greater than zero and  having the same month and date?

Comment: Sumproduct can be used in the same way as Countif, each of the checks for equality, like `(Month(Index(Data.A1463))=Month(A106))`, results in a TRUE or FALSE. When Booleans are applied in arithmetical operations (like multiplication) they automatically convert to 1 or 0. Thus, If the months are equal AND the years are equal, we end up with 1*1. Everything else produces a 0. Sumproduct then adds up all the 1's and 0's to tell you the number of times both conditions were met in the arrays.

Comment: Another way to do it is `Sumproduct(--(Month(Index(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=MONTH($A$106)), --(YEAR(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=YEAR($A$106)))`

Comment: Yes, SUMPRODUCT correctly counts occurrences of the given month/year combinations, but I need one level deeper - i need to count values in the specific column greater than zero within selected month/year region. (see the original question's working example with the case of MONTH())

Comment: Lets put it other way - Data sheet contains a lot of data having date as the first column and variable combinations of specific data in other columns - I need to count the number of non-zero occurrences of specific parameter (let it be Data.$B$1463:$B$1827) within month/year specified in A106.

Comment: `Sumproduct(--(Month(Index(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=MONTH($A$106)), --(YEAR(INDEX(Data.$A$1463:$A$1827))=YEAR($A$106)), --($B$1463:$B$1827>0))`

Comment: Excellen! btw - what syntax "--" means?

Comment: `--` is a way of forcing logical T/F values into 1/0 so that they can be summed.

Comment: Is there the way how to calculate the sum of the some other field using the information acquired by Sumproduct?